# Random Generate a Dictionary with random_names : random_integers

Tags: python-3.x

This code generate a set of random meaningless names:

```
def unique_names(k: int, ntokens: int,
               pool: str=string.ascii_letters) -> set:
    
    """
    Generate a set of unique string tokens.
    k: Length of each token
    ntokens: Number of tokens
    pool: Iterable of characters to choose from
    
    """
    seen = set()

    join = ''.join
    add = seen.add

    while len(seen) < ntokens:
        token = join(random.choices(pool, k=k))
        add(token)
    return seen
```

And its working.  I am now trying to generate random `k` numbers of `n digits_long integers`:

import random

```
def numbers(k: int ,n: int) -> set:
    
    l = set()
    join = ''.join
    add = l.add
    for _ in range(k):
    
        n= join(["{}".format(randint(0, 9)) for num in range(0, n)])
        add(n)
    return l
```

and the code above works if a genarate only 1 number:  `numbers(1,3) -> output {'134'}`  This is my first problem.

What i want to to is to genarate a `pair, value` dict os random names and numbers, like this:

```
{'vffde':234234, 'hrtge': 342344, ....}
```

So ill need to fix the 2nd code and somehow use both functions to gt the result dictionary of ramdom names:numbers.

I am having a hard time to make it happens. Can anyone helpe me?

Comment: Why not just use the same trick for uniqueness that you used in your first function? `while len(l) < k:`.. Then you can just `zip` the 2 together and send the result to `dict`. `my_dict = dict(zip(unique_names(5, 10), numbers(10, 6)))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with `dict(zip(...))` like so:

```py
def unique_names(k: int, ntokens: int,
                 pool: str = string.ascii_letters) -> set:
    """
    Generate a set of unique string tokens.
    k: Length of each token
    ntokens: Number of tokens
    pool: Iterable of characters to choose from

    """
    seen = set()

    join = ''.join
    add = seen.add

    while len(seen) < ntokens:
        token = join(random.choices(pool, k=k))
        add(token)
    return seen

def numbers(k: int, n: int) -> set:
    seen = set()
    join = ''.join
    add = seen.add
    while len(seen) < k:

        m = join(["{}".format(randint(0, 9)) for num in range(0, n)])
        add(m)
    return seen

random_pairs = dict(zip(unique_names(5,2), numbers(2, 6)))
```

There were two problems in your code: `n= join(["{}".format(randint(0, 9)) for num in range(0, n)])` is reusing the variable n, so when k > 1, you've converted your integer to a string. It should also be a while loop if you're trying to always have at least `k` entries.

You're also using `k` for a *very* different purpose in `unique_names` and `numbers`. This isn't currently a bug, but it is extremely likely to lead to more future bugs related to variable name shadowing.

Comment: Thanks.  This was dumb: didnt notice I was using n two times .-)  Huge Thanks mate.