# Counting equal values(collision) in python dict

Tags: python, python-3.x

This post was not useful to me [post_link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4865325/counting-collisions-in-a-python-dictionary)

So i am asking here:

i have a python dict:

```
a = {'Andres':234,'Paul':345,'Andres':675}
```

And I have this code

```
def get_index(dict, a_string):
    # Variable to store the result (updated after each iteration)
    result = 0
    #Variable to append the final result of each key in the dict
    collisions =[]
    
    for a_character in a_string:
        # Convert the character to a number (using ord)
        a_number = ord(a_character)
        # Update result by adding the number
        result += a_number
    collisions.append(result)
    
    # Take the remainder of the result with the size of the data list
    list_index = result % len(data_list)
    return collisions
```

That returns the unicode of a string, for exemple:

```
get_index(teste, 'Andres')
```

`returns [605]`

What a I want to to is tho pass my dict an for every key,value the code calculates de unicode_sum of the each string and append it to collisions:

I tried:

```
def get_index(dict):
    for k,v in teste.items:
          for a_character in a_string:
            # Convert the character to a number (using ord)
            a_number = ord(a_character)
            # Update result by adding the number
            result += a_number
        collisions.append(result)
```

What I want to get as result is:

```
get_index(a)

output: [605, 402, 605]
```

Then i can calculate the number of collision by just doing `len(collision) - set(collision)`

Comment: Look up [`collections.Counter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter).  It might make your task a whole lot easier.

Comment: Python isn't going to let you have the dictionary `{'Andres':234, 'Paul':345, 'Andres':675}`. What you actually have is `{'Andres':675, 'Paul':345}`.

Comment: This also isn't a reliable way to calculate collisions. There's more than string whose sum of ordinals is 605.

Comment: It's also not really clear why you're "calculating" collisions when Python is just going to overwrite any existing keys' value if you try to add the same key to a dictionary.

Comment: @ddejohn I got your point.  I put Andres twice just to have the same ord() result! I did ittrying to make it simple as in my hash function ( i will not use python dict) I´ll allow this to happen.

Comment: I just want to get both unicodes in a list.  It´s all I want.

Comment: I think you're misunderstanding. The sum of the ordinals of the string `"dnreAs"` will *also* be 605. Does that mean you'd consider that a "collision"?

Comment: @ddejohn yes ! In my project Andreas and dnreAs will be treated as collision because Ill get 2 ( or more) 605 sum!

Comment: What does your ***actual*** input look like? Are you working with a list of strings? Again, you won't be able to use a `dict` if you want both instances of `"Andres"` to be counted.

Comment: I have a dict with 5000 pairs of random names: value.   I am iterating each letter of each name(key) using ord(letter) and summing the result: I will get a list of 5000 integers. I want to know how many unique integers I have in this final list. And dosent matter if 2 or more strings sums to the same integer.  I just want to know how many uniques.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since `"Andres"` can't be present in your dictionary twice, I'll scramble the letters of the other instance to show that you'll get both results of `605`:

```py
>>> d = {"Andres": 234, "Paul": 345, "nAsedr": 675}
>>> collisions = [sum(map(ord, s)) for s in d]
>>> collisions
[605, 402, 605]
>>> len(collisions) - len(set(collisions))
1
```

This will also work for a `list` of strings, a `tuple` of strings, and a `set` of strings (where a `set` will also not allow you to have more than one `"Andres"`).

Comment: the names comes from this code: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69304159/random-generate-a-dictionary-with-random-names-random-integers/69304331#69304331]